# Expression: "(_Ptr_user&(_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1)) ==0" && 0

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I am working with Visual Studio and OpenCV. I have a simple code that detects keypoints and computes descriptors of two images.

```
void extractfeatures::extractKeypoints(cv::Mat _frame, cv::Mat _object)
{
    //Extract keypoints
    cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector;
    cv::Ptr<cv::AKAZE> akaze = cv::AKAZE::create();
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> object_keypoints, background_keypoints;
    cv::Mat desc1, desc2;
    akaze->detectAndCompute(_object, cv::noArray(), object_keypoints, desc1);
    akaze->detectAndCompute(_frame, cv::noArray(), background_keypoints, desc2);
}
```

The code works fine and it almost the same as the one give in the OpenCV Akaze documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/akaze_matching/akaze_matching.html

However, when it gets out of the function it gives me this error:

> Expression: "(_Ptr_user&(_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1)) ==0" && 0

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. I see this is mostly tied with VS2015, it doesn't show up in VS2013. Do you have similar observation? Did you get a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Because the memory of vector is limited, there are too many keypoints.
If the keypoints are about 10000：

```
object_keypoints.reserve(10000);
background_keypoints.reserve(10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I met such problem. It turned out that the program didn't link the right opencv's dll. When I moved the right dll, such as opencv_world310d.dll, to my program's Debug folder, this error disappeared.